# How to separate background from image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am using OpenCV 3.1 with Python 2.7. I am trying to separate background and foreground objects and have used this:

```
img = cv2.imread('testimage.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR);
fgbg = cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG2();
fgmask = fgbg.apply(img);
cv2.imshow("backsep",fgmask);
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/R.K.singh/Desktop/Image processing/background-sep.py", line
>   20, in 
>       fgbg = cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG2(); AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'BackgroundSubtractorMOG2'

Please help.

P.S: This question has been asked before however none of the solutions work.

Comment: I think it's `fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2();` you should use if we refer to the documentation <http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_video/py_bg_subtraction/py_bg_subtraction.html>

Comment: @AxelB. i get the error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\R.K.singh\Desktop\Image processing\background-sep.py", line 21, in <module>
    fgmask = fgbg.apply(img);
error: C:\builds\master_PackSlaveAddon-win32-vc12-static\opencv\modules\python\src2\cv2.cpp:163: error: (-215) The data should normally be NULL! in function NumpyAllocator::allocate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Axel suggested `cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG2()` is used to remove the background from video frames.

When it comes to images you can use the **GrabCut Algorithm** . The OpenCV documentation contains a [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d8/d83/tutorial_py_grabcut.html) including the relevant Python code.

You can also watch these videos for better understanding of **Image Segmentation**:

- [Digital image processing: p042 - Interactive Image Segmentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KXQuR-lnVFQ&index=43&list=PLZ9qNFMHZ-A79y1StvUUqgyL-O0fZh2rs)
- [Digital image processing: p043 Graph Cuts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HMGX8HXskKk&index=44&list=PLZ9qNFMHZ-A79y1StvUUqgyL-O0fZh2rs)